# Avoiding repeating the same EventTriggers in many UserControls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a bunch of UserControls where I define EventTriggers bindings for Loaded and Closed Events. I would like to create some custom user control or just a container which will define all necessary bindings and simply reuse it. I managed to solve it using custom ContentControl but I wonder if there is any better way to do it.

Below you can find my current code:

Defining container

```
public class StandardEventsContainer : ContentControl{}
```

Defining styles for container

```
<Style TargetType="containers:StandardEventsContainer">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="containers:StandardEventsContainer">
                <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding WindowLoadedCommand}" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closed">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding WindowClosedCommand}" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </ContentControl>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Using it inside UserControl

```
<UserControl 
  x:Class="MyNamespace.MyUserControl"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
<StandardEventsContainer>
    <Grid>
      Some content...
    </Grid>
</baseContainers:StandardEventsContainer>
```

And obviously I have View Model bound to this control.
Its working fine but I would rather want to have custom user control (EventsUserControl) defining these bindings so that I can tell my DI that ViewModel bound to control inheriting from EventsUserControl need to implement interface as well.

Comment: Can't you apply these using a style?  What do the command do? Could they be re usable static commands?  You've not explained sufficiently.

Comment: These are just commands which run when control is loaded and closed. They should be implemented in most of my view models so static command is not an option. 

Sure I can apply it using style and also I can leave it as it is because its working but right now its magic knowledge for my View Model that it need to implement these commands.  I would love to have custom User Control which somehow define these bindings and then I could inherit from this custom user control in my controls.

Comment: If it's lifecycle events you're after I'd strongly recommend using an existing framework (eg [CaliburnMicro's Screen](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/composition)) and using the provided lifecycle methods on the base ViewModel (eg `OnActivate()` in the first example).

Comment: `UserControl` has not a `Close` event. As suggested, the triggers can be set in a style and the commands do not need mandatory be static, you just need to provide, that object set for `UserControl.DataContext` has such a command. Alternatively appropriate logic can be implemented in a `Behavior`.